# Собеседование Junior Developer C/Objective-C

Tags: c, objective-c

Что нужно обязательно повторить перед собеседованием? Какие алгоритмы? Структуры данных? И т.п.? Может паттерны какие почитать?

Comment: А вкогда собеседование?

Comment: @dzhioev во вторник

Comment: 100% будут спрашивать типа "покажи прожку на аппсторе" =) все зависит от конторы, может поулыбаешься и возьмут, могут спросить логические задачи, алгоритмы на рекурсию любят...

Comment: "может поулыбаешься и возьмут" - с большой долей вероятности, IOS разрабы, пока еще - крайне востребованы.

Comment: ну прожку просить наверное не будут, тк я скорее стажером иду.. 
а тестовые задачи давали олимпиадные (на динамическое программирование, на поиск подстрок и еще фигня какая то))  
просто интересно как глубоко гонять будут ? часто ли просят написать код ? и тп

Comment: меня больше удивляется - разве нету в нэте таких статей?

Comment: @paul - скорее всего по коду вас особо гонять не будут, на данный момент это крайне дефицитная сфера (примерно так-же как и JS html5 разработчики). Тут важно понимание, желание и хоть какой-то опыт.

Вообще - не думайте о том, что будут спрашивать. Какая разница? Если вы им не подходите - пару вопросов которые вы, например, каким то чудом угадаете и т.д. вас не спасут. А если подходите - то все будет путем =)

Comment: @AlexWindHope если бы у меня был хоть какой то опыт - я бы не думал))

Answer (score 4):

Меня три месяца назад спрашивали следующее:
 - какие патерны программирования повсеместно используются в iOS Sdk,
 - написать сеттергеттер для свойства считая что ARC нет
 - написать процедуру, инвертирующую массив символов (первый элемент должен стать последним, второй пердпоследним и т.д.) на с, допвопрос по написанному был про мелкие улучшения кода типа что можно ускорить в for (int i=0; i<b/2; ++i) (считая, что у нас тупой компилятор и сам он с этим не справится)
 - жизненный цикл viewController'а
 - были вопросы про многопоточность и конкретно что есть что в вызове одиночки в obj-c

Было еще что-то (всего собеседование длилось часа 2-3 включая разговор что делал раньше в т.ч. не по работе и рассказ о компании), но уже не помню + я не на джуниора шел, скорее на мидла (должность звучит как software engineer, должности джуниора и сеньера в компании есть отдельно)

Comment: @aknew хм, понятно. я просто иду на собеседование не то juniorа не то стажера objective-c. Но мне по телефону еще сказали, что я думаю, если меня возьмут  wpf  разработчиком - я то сказал что согласен, но ничего не знаю)) я только на с/java пишу и то пока только для себя.

Comment: @aknew, а что за компания, если не секрет? Просто странный уровень вопросов не для junior'a.

Comment: я, пожалуй, опущу название :) Что касается уровня вопросов, сами понимаете - я написал что помню в общем виде, а когда было собеседование к ним цеплялись другие вопросы, уточнения по не совсем стандартным ситуациям и тп, не все они были по obj-c, например, вопросы по bash я писать не стал т.к. они там были факультативно и топикстартеру их давать вряд ли будут. А вообще после вашего поста я подумал, что это перечень скорее тех вопросов (или похожих где-то была сортировка вместо массива), которые попались на каждом собеседовании, на которые я сходил, а дальше шли у всех разные, я их уже не помн

Comment: @aknew, А, ну тогда понятно. Сам я на собеседованиях не был (рано еще), но знакомые (по obj-c тоже, но разработка для Mac OS), которые ходили на что-то вроде мидла, говорили про вопросы о GCD, runtime'e, замыканиях, описание процесса инициализации приложения вместе с UI (+написать GUI-приложение, создающееся полностью "руками"). Ну т.е. более "практические" вещи, что ли. Вот и удивил список вопросов :)